# Rotating the nearest rectangles

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

The main code(init):

```
package  {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;
    import flash.geom.Point;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;

    public class Init extends Sprite {

        var parts:Array,
        images:Array,
        w:Number = 20,
        h:Number = 80,
        numParts:int = stage.stageWidth / w,
        i:int,
        imgCount:int = 0,
        timer:Timer,
        rc:Number = 0,
        vr:Number = 10;
        public function Init() {
            init();
        }


        function init():void
        {
            parts = new Array();
            images = new Array(new Img1(), new Img2());

            for(i = 0; i < numParts; i++)
            {
                var img2:BitmapData = new BitmapData(w, h);
                img2.copyPixels(images[imgCount], new Rectangle(i * w, 0, w, h), new Point());
                var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(img2);
                bitmap.x = -w / 2
                var rect:Rect = new Rect();
                rect.addChild(bitmap);
                rect.x = i * w + w / 2;
                addChild(rect);
                parts.push(rect);
            }
            i = 0;
            timer = new Timer(2000);
            timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTick);
            timer.start();
        }

        function onTick(e:TimerEvent):void
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
            timer.stop();
        }

        function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void
        {
            rotate2();
        }

        function rotate2()
        {
            parts[i].rotationY += vr;
            parts[i].rc += vr;
            if(parts[i].rc >= 180)
            {
                parts[i].rc = 0;
                parts[i].rotationY = 0;
                i++;
                if(i >= numParts)
                {
                    i = 0;
                    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
                    timer.start();
                }
            }
            else
            if(parts[i].rc == 90)
            {

                parts[i].imgCount++;
                if(parts[i].imgCount >= images.length){parts[i].imgCount = 0;}
                    var img2:BitmapData = new BitmapData(w, h);
                    img2.copyPixels(images[parts[i].imgCount], new Rectangle(i * w, 0, w, h), new Point());
                    var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(img2);
                    bitmap.x = -w / 2
                    parts[i].redraw(bitmap);
                    parts[i].rotationY = -90;

            }

        }

        function rotate1()
        {
            for(i = 0; i < numParts; i++)
            {
                parts[i].rotationY += vr;
            }
            rc += vr;
            if(rc == 180)
            {
                removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
                timer.start();
                rc = 0;
            }
            else
            if(rc == 90)
            {
                imgCount++;
                if(imgCount >= images.length){imgCount = 0;}
                for(i = 0; i < numParts; i++)
                {
                    var img2:BitmapData = new BitmapData(w, h);
                    img2.copyPixels(images[imgCount], new Rectangle(i * w, 0, w, h), new Point());
                    var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(img2);
                    bitmap.x = -w / 2
                    parts[i].redraw(bitmap);
                    parts[i].rotationY = -90;
                }

            }
        }

    }

}
```

the Rect class:

```
package  {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Rect extends Sprite {

        public var imgCount:int = 0,
        rc:int = 0;
        public function Rect() {
            init();
        }


        private function init():void
        {

        }

        public function redraw(bitmap):void
        {
            removeChildAt(0);
            addChild(bitmap);
        }

    }

}
```

description:

Here I have 2 methods, the rotate1 - rotates all the rectangles at one time, and the rotate2 rotates each rectangle after he rotates 180 degrees and then rotates the next rectangle, so what I want to do is to rotate the nearest rectangles from the current, lets say the nearest 3 rectangles and they are rotating a half of the speed from the current, how can I do this using this code..

ps: you can try this code by importing some images...

Comment: and when each of the rectangle who has reached 80 degrees will change the part of the picture incrementing parts[i].imgCount++, how to add this functionallity to the neares rectangles

Comment: are these rectangles arranged in a grid or 2D array?  At first I thought they were all floating randomly on the page, but in order to get an answer, you're going to have to be more specific about what it is you have and need.

Comment: here is something you may want to play with... it would eliminate all of your bitmap copying and moving.. and also make it a 1 liner to rotate a clip around a new registration point (it's center).  I'm not sure of the quality of this class (never used it) but it looks like it does exactly what you are after [Link to Class Page](http://www.oscartrelles.com/archives/dynamic_movieclip_registration_with_as3)

Comment: I split an image into parts and then add each part to each rectangle, then rotate each rectangle onEnterFrame, so how can I rotate the nearest rectangles with the current?